# PolygonRegion creating anr

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx

I'm try create mask for cut texture. User moving finger on the screen and when he will up finger mask will created. My problem in, after user has long time moved on screen and up finger, mask start creating, and I have had anr in line

```
PolygonRegion polyReg = new PolygonRegion(textRegion, coord);
```

where coord it float array and textRegion it object TextureRegion with texture in which need to draw. It problem happens when user long time move on the screen. First time I think  that PolygonRegion can't resolved to many point, but after I have understand it not count of point problem(sometime I have anr with 160 point and sometime I haven't anr with 1000 point). Maybe someone take same problem and can say what it could be.
Code:

```
if(maskBufferer != null){
 maskBufferer.dispose();
 }
 maskBufferer = new FrameBuffer(Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888, width, height, true);
 mask = createMaskImageMask(aspectRatioCrop, maskBufferer);
 ...

private Texture createMaskImageMask(boolean aspectRatioCrop, FrameBuffer maskBufferer) {
    maskBufferer.begin();

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(COLOR_FOR_MASK, COLOR_FOR_MASK, COLOR_FOR_MASK, ALPHA_FOR_MASK);
    Gdx.graphics.getGL20().glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    float[] coord = null;
    coord = mCoodrinateArray.getCoodrinatesInScreenSize();
    mCoodrinateArray.clean();
    PolygonRegion polyReg = new PolygonRegion( new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(texturePolygon)) ),
        coord);
    PolygonSprite poly = new PolygonSprite(polyReg);
    PolygonSpriteBatch polyBatch = new PolygonSpriteBatch();
    polyBatch.begin();
    poly.draw(polyBatch);
    polyBatch.end();

    maskBufferer.end();

    texture.dispose();
    polyBatch.dispose();
    return maskBufferer.getColorBufferTexture();
}
```

In onMove code:

```
Vector3 vec = MathUtils.toGlFromScreenV3(detector.getCurrEvent().getX(),    detector.getCurrEvent().getY(), mWidth, mHeight);
mCoodrinateArray.addCoordinate(vi.x, vi.y);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. This was a bug in LibGDX old version. Solution is simple update libGDX, and read doc. Because logic of polygons has changed.